# Parameter passing with usr/bin/php p in cron jobs

Tags: php, linux, symfony-1.4, cron-task, crontrigger

I have a problem with cron task creating. I created the task, and its working just fine on my server if I run the following command:

```
php symfony namespace:taskname
```

At the crontab I use the following command:

```
usr/bin/php /home/user/mysite/symfony namespace:taskname
```

If I run this command, I only get the `symfony` commands list. In other words, it looks the same as if I type in just `php symfony`. Somehow the `namespace:taskname` part is not passed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ask my system administrator with this issue, and he told me to use the following syntax in the crontab:

`php-cli /home/user/mysite/symfony namespace:taskname`

Now its working just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to write syntax like

```
X X X X X  usr/bin/php /home/user/mysite/symfony namespace:taskname
```

where  `X X X X X` is time period in which you want to run command . also set time according to your task completion time. it may overlap time.

> still same problem  then it may be your timezone is not ok in php.ini
>   file. set your timezone in php.ini file.

Comment: Of course i made the syntax like that. I set it to run in every minute but nothing happens. The server is not mine, I dont think I can change anything in the php.ini.

Comment: @Tóth Arnold ,  i am giving a link where most of problem of crontab is shared . go through http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work . check  your crontab is ok and it may be your  symfony command is not ok that i dont know more about symfony .